# ETC1 compressed textures not working on Motorola Atrix

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

our live wallpaper doesn't work properly on Motorola Atrix phone. It has a stock ROM w/ Android 2.3.
It looks like `discard` command of fragment shader doesn't work resulting image without transparent parts.
The problem doesn't appear on Desire S w/ Android 2.3, Mototola Droid w/ CM9, ASUS Transformer w/ 4.0, Samsung Galaxy Note w/ 4.0. So the problem seems to be very specific to Motorola Atrix phone.
We use ETC1 compressed textures so alpha channel is passed to shader via separate texture sampler - `sTexture` is used for main diffuse texture and `sAlpha` has black-and-white alpha channel.

Here is code for fragment and vertex shaders:

```
private final String mVertexShader = "uniform highp mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
        "attribute highp vec4 aPosition;\n" +
        "attribute highp vec2 aTextureCoord;\n" +
        "varying mediump vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
        "  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;\n" +
        "}\n";

private final String mAlphaFragmentShader = "precision mediump float;\n" +
        "varying mediump vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D sAlpha;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        " vec4 base = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
        " gl_FragColor = base;\n" +
        " if(texture2D(sAlpha, vTextureCoord).r < 0.5){ discard; }\n" +
        "}";
```

Comment: Does `base.a` exist and is it ever above 0.5?

Comment: @tolgap Sorry, wrong shader code (it was the old shader which used alpha channel of single texture, ETC1 textures have no alpha so I've modified shader to use 2 textures). I've edited question - now it has correct vertex and fragment shaders.

Comment: I use an Atrix for my development device and my `discard` statements work fine. If you try to do something else inside the if block aside from discard does it work? (say, set the color to yellow instead of discard).

Comment: @Tim I haven't tried this because I don't have access to the phone. All I have is bug report from one customer, and I can't ask her to test my apps. If this won't bother you, I can create a few test builds of app and send them to you. I can also make a few more builds just to test correctness of texture sampling, etc. Could I contact you by your email from Google Play? (I've found a link to your Google Play app in your stackoverflow profile). I will appreciate your help, because I desperately need to test app on Atrix.

Comment: @keaukraine - You have my permission to send me an email. I'm not running a QA department, but I can probably do a *very limited* feature check on an apk. If you need more thorough than that I suggest you look for a cheap used device on ebay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I've fixed this. Many thanks to @Tim for willing to run test apps on device and providing me screenshots.
I've modified fragment shader the following way:

```
private final String mAlphaFragmentShader = "precision mediump float;\n" +
        "varying mediump vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D sAlpha;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        " vec4 base = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
        " vec4 mask = texture2D(sAlpha, vTextureCoord);\n" +
        " gl_FragColor = base;\n" +
        " if(mask.g < 0.5){ discard; }\n" +
        "}";
```

It seems that Motorola Atrix OpenGL drivers treat compressed textures in wrong way and sample *R* channel as *A* channel which is always 1.0 in case of ETC1 compressed textures. It looks like internal format of texture is treated as *ARGB* instead of *RGBA*. Since my mask texture is black-and-white I can fetch any other colour. Green works just fine.

Comment: Glad you were able to find a solution. I have edited the title of the question to more accurately reflect the problem, such that it may help others with the same problem (ETC1 textures).